# Azure Logic Apps - When a new email arrives workflow does not trigger

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create an Azure Logic App Workflow to extract attachments when email arrives.

I have a workflow on my account to generate Logic App design.

This workflow is directly paste in our azuredeploy.json file to be deploy with our pipeline on the Azure Logic App main account.

[image]

This workflow works perfectly on my app but not in the deployed app. In the deployed app, when I send an email to test the workflow, it does not trigger the event like it does in my account.

It seems that our issue came from the office365 email that we specially created (which is different from ours) the be used to get email with attachments.

And now I just tried with the trigger "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox" and it work exactly as expected. But it's not a shared mailbox !

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have created your connection to Office 365 (Outlook) using your own account, which would explain why it works for you, and the Shared Mailbox (which only requires one having access to it).

However, your scenario requires the "delegated permissions" model, for which Graph API is better suited.

May I kindly suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http